# Javascript library string prototype

Tags: javascript, module

I'm creating a javascriptt library, and I need to add a function to the prototype of the String class, (isEmpty function), I can't really understand whether this will be global in all the project.
Let's say the user of the library added a function with the same name to the String prototype, will that override the one in the library?

Comment: **Yes** for the first and **Yes** for the second!

Comment: This is why you should not add a function to the prototype of built-in objects unless you absolutely know what you're doing. Instead, define a function in your own library, like `isEmpty(s)`, where `s` is a string. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/215552 for more info.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks, is there any thing we do about that ? like to avoid conflict ?

Comment: Do as @MikeMcCaughan said! It's not a good practice to alter those built-in objects. And if the library uses them (functions) internally then no need to add them to the prototype at all.